# Add line between prints in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I wrote a function that prints a frequency table for all variables in a data frame that are factors.

To know the variable of the printed frequency tables, I added

```
print(colnames(dataframe)[i])
```

that prints the column name.

Function:

```
freq_factor <- function(dataframe, n_factors = 5)
  {
  for (i in 1:length(dataframe))
    {
    if ((is.factor(dataframe[,i]) == "TRUE") & (nlevels(dataframe[,i]) <= 10))
      {
      print(colnames(dataframe)[i])
      print(table(dataframe[,i]))
      }
    }
}
```

I want an output where there is a white line between frequency table of variable 1 and the column name of variable 2.

Desired output:

```
[1] "column name 1"
factor 1 factor 2
1           10

[1] "column name 2"
factor 1 factor 2 factor 3
10        6         16
```

But I get a white line between column name of variable 1 and frequency table of variable 1, without a white line after that frequency table.

Real output:

```
[1] "column name 1"

factor 1 factor 2
1           10
[1] "column name 2"

factor 1 factor 2 factor 3
10        6         16
```

How can I get a white line after the frequency table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `cat` statement in place of the first `print` statement:

```
cat("\n", colnames(dataframe)[i], sep = "")
```